# EnableRule in ribbon cannot get boolean value from async function

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, es6-promise, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365

I want to return `true` or `false` from the function `showHideAddNewButton`. I have an `EnableRule` in a ribbon button, which calls a custom rule that calls this function `showHideAddNewButton`. On passing either `true`, which will show the button, or `false`, which will hide the button.

I have to access `statuscode` (Status Reason) and `statecode` (Status) fields on the entity. I have created a query using the `Xrm.WebApi.retrieveMultipleRecords`, but cannot get it to return a flag. I want the `retrieveMultipleRecords` method to only execute on and never be called again but 'return true' below gets executed setting my button to true always.

```js
function showHideAddNewCsrsRecalculation(primaryControl){
    var fileNumber = primaryControl.getAttribute("ssg_filenumber").getValue();
    
        Xrm.WebApi.retrieveMultipleRecords("rrg_csrsfile", "?$select=statuscode,statecode,rr_filenumber&$filter=rr_filenumber eq '" + fileNumber + "'").then(
            function success(result) {
                for (var i = 0; i < result.entities.length; i++) {
                    var statusCode = result.entities[i].statecode; 
                    var statusReasonCode = result.entities[i].statuscode; 
                    
                    //if draft make button invisible
                    if (statusReasonCode == 8676725)
                       return false;
                    //if submitted make button invisible
                     if (statusReasonCode == 8676726)
                       return false; 
    
                    //if inactive make button invisible
                     if (statusCode == 1)
                       return false;
                }           
            },
            function (error) {
                console.log(error.message);
                // handle error conditions
            }
        );
        
    //if draft make button invisible
    //if (primaryControl.getAttribute("statuscode").getValue() == 867670025)
    //   return false; 
    //if submitted make button invisible
    //if (primaryControl.getAttribute("statuscode").getValue() == 867670026)
    //  return false; 
    
    //if inactive make button invisible
    //if (primaryControl.getAttribute("statecode") != 'undefined' && primaryControl.getAttribute("statecode").getValue() == 1)
    //  return false;
    
    //other options make button visible
      return true; --> This keeps getting called as a result my button is always visible
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Function `Xrm.WebApi.retrieveMultipleRecords` returns a *promise*, not an actual boolean value. The function is executed asynchronously, so immediately after the call to this function the next line is executed and that line always returns `true`.

In fact it is not possible to make an asynchronous call synchronous. Instead we can follow another approach by following these steps:

1. Do the query in the form's onload function and store the result in a variable.
2. Refresh the ribbon.
3. Create a ribbon button handler returning the variable's value.

```js
let isRecalculationButtonVisible = false;

function onLoad(context) {
    const formContext = context.getFormContext();

    const filter = "$filter=rr_filenumber eq '"
        + formContext.getAttribute("ssg_filenumber").getValue()
        + "' and (statecode eq 1 or statuscode eq 8676725 or statuscode eq 8676726)";

    Xrm.WebApi.retrieveMultipleRecords("rrg_csrsfile", "?$select=rrg_csrsfileid&$top=1&" + filter)
        .then(function (result) {
            isRecalculationButtonVisible = result.entities.length === 0;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error.message);
        })
        .finally(() => {
            formContext.ui.refreshRibbon(false);
        });
}

function showHideAddNewCsrsRecalculation() {
    return isRecalculationButtonVisible;
}
```

As you probably already noticed I added a few improvements.

1. All your button needs to know is *if* there are any records meeting specific conditions, so there is no need to actually retrieve them. Therefore these conditions can simply be placed in the query's filter. I also added a `$top=1`, because the number of records meeting the conditions is not relevant here. As a consequence the only check that needs to be done is whether a record is returned or not.
2. As explained, `retrieveMultipleRecords` returns a promise. The recommended error handling for promises is adding a `catch` function at the end of the chain.